# Change the width of the cell content

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to change the width of the cell content. (see the pic)
[alt text http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/tv_cell_parts.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/tv_cell_parts.jpg)

My code:

```
 CGSize contentViewSize = cell.contentView.bounds.size;
    contentViewSize.width = 20.0f;
```

But there is no effect, what's wrong?
Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi

Maybe the layout is done by the tableView and is overriding your settings.
If you NSLog out the width just after you set it, does it say 20.0?

I usually make my own UIView for the cell if I need anything that is not very close to standard.

Comment: Yes, it say 20.0. Thanks your suggestion for UIView.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-assign the `frame` for the cell's `contentView`.

```
CGRect oldFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake( oldFrame.origin.x,
                                     oldFrame.origin.y, 
                                     oldFrame.size.width + 20, 
                                     oldFrame.size.height );
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually I want to change the width of both textLabel and detailTextLabel, so I also tried set the width       <code>"CGSize contentViewSize = cell.contentView.bounds.size;
    contentViewSize.width = 20.0f;"</code>      . doesn't work, either...thanks though.